# OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget :- Android

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

i am downloading images from Url and displaying them. At download time it is giving 
`out of memory error : bitmap size exceeds VM budget`. 
I am using drawable. Code is below:

```
HttpClient httpclient= new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response=(HttpResponse)httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
HttpEntity entity= response.getEntity();
BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity=new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
InputStream instream = bufHttpEntity.getContent();

Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(instream);
Bitmap useThisBitmap = 
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm,bm.getWidth(),bm.getHeight(), true);
bm.recycle();
BitmapDrawable bt= new BitmapDrawable(useThisBitmap);
System.gc();
```

Here is the error:

```
`05-28 14:55:47.251: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4188): 
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget`
```

Comment: If the image is really big this solution should help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue/823966#823966

Comment: Hi,, Marcelo Cantos!!! ..height & width of image= 320x320

Comment: Find Out in how many ways u can fetch the images so that u don't find the memory issue

Comment: Thanks OM The Eternity,,, i have tried... but main problem is VM...

Comment: I know I'm a bit late, but what if the image is generated and at the point of creating it (`img = Bitmap.createBitmap(size.x, size.y, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);`) it will crash?

Comment: @dragon112 You could check the available memory before trying to create a bitmap - depending on how big ur bitmap is going to be, you should check if enough memory is available for allocation. Beware though: Before API Level 11 Bitmaps were allocated on the native heap (use the class "Debug" to call methods that give u the available native heap etc..), starting from API Level 11 Bitmaps are completely allocated on the VM Heap. Use Runtime.getRuntime()'s method to check the available VM heap.

Comment: 2 things causes this: too big local images or too big remote images. In 1st case, manually resize all. In case when you fetch images from some server, then resize images in code.

Comment: when you call bitmap.recycle after you created a new `createScaledBitmap` you wanna make sure that the on you recycle is not the same object as the one you just got back. Android documentation says: If the specified width and height are the same as the current width and height of the source btimap, the source bitmap is returned and now new bitmap is created.

Answer (score 32):

Use `decodeStream(is, outPadding, opts)` with

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts=new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inDither=false;                     //Disable Dithering mode
opts.inPurgeable=true;                   //Tell to gc that whether it needs free memory, the Bitmap can be cleared
opts.inInputShareable=true;              //Which kind of reference will be used to recover the Bitmap data after being clear, when it will be used in the future
opts.inTempStorage=new byte[32 * 1024];
```

Answer (score 6):

You could check the image size and then downsample it by appropriate factor.

See this question: [Handling large Bitmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220949/handling-large-bitmaps)

Answer (score 2):

This issue seems to have been reported several times, [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg16231.html) and [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg21043.html) for instance...
sorry Shalini but if it's the same issue, it seems that there is no solution at all...

The only advice of Romain Guy is [to use less memory...](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg18960.html)

So, good luck to think your stuff differently...

Comment: There is a solution: use less memory than the maximum allowed. I know this is a frustrating answer but phones do not have "unlimited" amount of RAM like desktop machines. You have to be careful.

Comment: Didn't know you were coming on stack ;)
As I said, your recommandation was to use less memory...
What would you advise to do for that? reduce the size of the picture?

Comment: @RomainGuy P.S. it's now 2020 and my phone has 4GB of RAM

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after resample the image as suggested above, you may call [bitmap_file.recycle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle()).

Answer (score 0):

The FACT is that there is a BUG on some Android versions, particularly version 2.1 fails all the time with issues like this one.

I released an app in which I have took a lot of care on resource use. I have even deleted a lot of bitmaps that I were using and now they are created on the fly using graphic primitives. I also recycle bitmaps when no using them. And of course I have checked that I have no memory leaks in my app: the used memory does NOT grow without control, it keeps all the time within reasonable values.

Although I have invest a lot of effort on trying to avoid this problem, I continue getting lots of annoying exceptions like that from 2.1 and 2.1-update1 devices. I am using critercism now to report crashes, and I have seen that It occurs even when the app is using just 4 megabytes of RAM, four times less than the 16M of heap size that every Android device must have for an app -and the fact is that most of devices these days have heap sizes bigger than 16M-.

All my bitmaps have a size of 800x480 pixels, that on the worst case as ARGB_8888 may not occupy more than 1.5MB each one, but it crashes trying to load one when having just 4 megabytes occupied, so there should be at least another 12 MB free. And most of my Bitmaps are loaded as ARGB_4444 that occupies a half of memory, I only use ARGB_8888 when the bitmaps looks really poor with 4444.

So for me it is pretty clear that there is something on these Android versions that is not working fine. 99'9% of this crashes comes from 2.1 and 2.1-update, and the rest may be explained by other punctual reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried many things this is what works.

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts=new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inDither=false;                     //Disable Dithering mode
opts.inPurgeable=true;        
opts.inScale=8;
///after you use your images
System.gc();
```

Comment: Requesting garbage collection will not clean up a memory leak.

Answer (score -2):

This is a practical answer, what I tried to avoid this problem at Run-time. And it also solved my problem.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
```

Calling Garbage Collector is a good Idea.

Comment: This doesn't explicitly call the garbage collector but it recommends the virtual machine to do it.

Comment: If you're leaking memory this will do absolutely nothing. Garbage collections only recycle objects that don't have anything else hanging onto a reference to them.