# OutOfMemory when load image to bitmap from URL

Tags: android

I load image from url. it' ok, but when long time it error outofmemory:  bitmap size exceeds vm budget. here my code

```
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions;
    bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    //from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        InputStream is=new URL(url).openStream();
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, bmOptions);
        is.close();
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = 1;
        is = new URL(url).openStream();
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, o2);
        is.close();
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
       return null;
    }
```

help me please!!

Comment: Which line does it error out on?

Comment: How big is the image? Check out this question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928002/outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [sampleSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize) of BitmapFactory.Options, this will reduce the size in memory of your image (and the quality)

But if your image is really too big, I think that's there no miracle solution, the image is simply too big ...

Comment: i use simpleSize image to tiny cause image it large

Comment: Uh sorry I missed it ^^'. But I think that a value of 1 doesn't change anything, "If set to a value > 1, requests the decoder to subsample the original image, returning a smaller image to save memory." (from Android reference)

Comment: my app load image from url to show pic that image is large. In listview i use simplesize but in imageview if i use ismplesize > 1, that image to smaller.

Comment: So I think there's nothing to do :/ As I said there's no miracle solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is exactly what stated in error message: your image is too big to be loaded into memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try with any other image. As this image is exceding the size of ur folder.

R u using Emulator to test it?

Answer (score 0):

Just a idea, it could be this piece of code throws sometime a exception. This will causes that the InputStream will not release rthe asigned resources (memory leak).

if you close the Input stream in a finaly block this issue should be solved