# OutOfMemoryError when opening lot of little pictures

Tags: android, bitmap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget :- Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928002/outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android)

In my application I load some little Bitmap(between 2k and 300k) that I affect to ImageViews, during the first launch of my App it works fine but when I quit it and relaunch it, I always have the OutOfMemoryError during a Bitmap creation.

Could somebody tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because your bitmap's size is too large than the VM can handle. For example from your code I can see that you are trying to paste an Image into imageView which you are capturing using Camera. So normally the camera images will be too large in size which will rise this error obviously. So as others have suggested, you have to compress your image either by sampling it or convert your image into smaller resolution. For example if your imageView is 100x100 in width and height, you can create a scaled bitmap so that your imageView gets filled exactly. You can do this for that,

```
Bitmap newImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 350, 300,true);
```

And you have to recycle your bitmap and null your bitmap like this,

```
Bitmap bmap.recycle();
Bitmap bmap=null;
```

Comment: Thanks! I really don't understand why android GC don't treat Bitmap like any other Object...

Answer (score 0):

You should use `bitmap.recycle()` manually when you leave your activity.

Please refer to [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29)

Comment: I was a litte bit feared by this kind of answer..So the GC is not very usefull for Bitmap..Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt you have to use `bitmap.recycle()` if you null your references, allowing GC (but please prove me wrong).

I'd say it's more likely your bitmaps are too large, [possibly aggravated by long lived `Context` references](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) or somesuch.