# Out of memory error occurred when handling more than One image

Tags: android, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget :- Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928002/outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android)

I have code like following,  and captured image has size around 300KB. If the `imageCount = 1` it works properly that means it can handle one image without memory exception. But when we have more  than one image, it produces `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:bitmap size exceeds VM budget`. I think the problem is, after each iteration of `for loop` the allocated space for `bitmap,byte array and string`is do not make free. I tried  System.gc(), no use. How can i solve this????

```
try{

                            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http:url");
                            for( int i = 0; i <= imageCount; i++ ) {
                                String methodName = "new_receipt";
                                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator +  "captured_receipt"+i+".jpg");
                                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); //6291456 9555000
                                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, baos); //bm is the bitmap object   
                                byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
                                String encodedImage = Base64.encodeBytes(b);//Base64.DEFAULT               
                                json.put("Key", key);
                                json.put("image_no", i);
                                json.put("image",encodedImage);
                                methodName = "add_image";
                                List<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>(3);
                                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("module", "expense"));
                                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("method", methodName));
                                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", json.toString()));
                                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs)); 
                                response = client.execute(post);
                            }
                           } catch(Exception e){
                                  Log.d("MY Error",e.getMessage());
                              }
```

Comment: Refer to my answer here. 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909128/outofmemoryerror-when-opening-lot-of-little-pictures/6909204#6909204][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909128/outofmemoryerror-when-opening-lot-of-little-pictures/6909204#6909204

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried this, but got the same error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `bm.recycle()` and `bm=null` after each post to the server.

EDIT: I think it is useless to create a `Bitmap` for every file. You could just read the file into a `StringBuffer` and pass this to your `JSONObject`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately nothing changed. What will I do??

Comment: I used `bm.recycle()` and `bm = null`, and replaced `JSON` with a text file, then it works!!!