# Getting error: external allocation too large for this process

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to implement the code below converting a image path into a bitmap to display on my activity. I am getting the below error. I have tried a bunch of different solutions but none are working

[Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

[Android: Resize a large bitmap file to scaled output file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331527/android-resize-a-large-bitmap-file-to-scaled-output-file)

[OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget :- Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928002/outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android)

Error: 
E/dalvikvm-heap(19252): 12742656-byte external allocation too large for this process.

```
for(int i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {

     File imgFile = new  File(photoPaths.get(i));

        if(imgFile.exists())
        {

             images[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());


        }
```

Comment: Try harder? I know for a fact that this one works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object/823966#823966

Answer (score 1):

You may consider loading them in a more just-in-time kind of approach, or using the `inSampleSize` option of the bitmap factory (i.e., you'd pass a `BitmapFactory.Options` in to the factory with `inSampleSize` set to, ideally, a power of 2).  Also make sure you set `inPurgeable` true.

In the event that you are pulling these images from the `MediaStore`'s `ContentProvider`, you can also use [thumbnails](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.html).

Perhaps you can tell us more about your use case so we can better help.

Comment: Thumbs up for the inPurgeable=true suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to load multiple large bitmaps, at least one of which is ~12MB. They're too large. The solutions you posted DO work. Resize your bitmaps to something much smaller, especially as you're just displaying the bitmaps on the screen.