# Android Out of memory regarding png image

Tags: android, image-processing, gimp

I have a jpg image in my app that shows correctly. In my listview i'd like to make the image more transparent so it is easier to see the text. I changed the image to a png format and altered it's opacity in GIMP.

Now that the new image is in the app drawable folder. Im getting the following error. why?

```
   09-28 09:24:07.560: I/global(20140): call socket shutdown, tmpsocket=Socket[address=/178.250.50.40,port=80,localPort=35172]
09-28 09:24:07.570: I/global(20140): call socket shutdown, tmpsocket=Socket[address=/212.169.27.217,port=84,localPort=55656]
09-28 09:24:07.690: D/dalvikvm(20140): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 113K, 4% free 38592K/39907K, paused 32ms
09-28 09:24:07.690: I/dalvikvm-heap(20140): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 28072816-byte allocation
09-28 09:24:07.740: D/dalvikvm(20140): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 4% free 38582K/39907K, paused 43ms
09-28 09:24:07.740: E/dalvikvm-heap(20140): Out of memory on a 28072816-byte allocation.
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40a57490 self=0x1b6e9a8
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   | sysTid=20140 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1074361640
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   | schedstat=( 2289118000 760844000 2121 ) utm=195 stm=33 core=1
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:486)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2042)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2812)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:410)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:174)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:170)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:278)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1897)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at com.carefreegroup.ShowMoreDetails.onCreate(ShowMoreDetails.java:26)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4543)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2181)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2260)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-28 09:24:07.740: I/dalvikvm(20140):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-28 09:24:07.740: E/dalvikvm(20140): Out of memory: Heap Size=46115KB, Allocated=38582KB, Limit=65536KB
09-28 09:24:07.740: E/dalvikvm(20140): Extra info: Footprint=39907KB, Allowed Footprint=46115KB, Trimmed=892KB
09-28 09:24:07.740: E/Bitmap_JNI(20140): Create Bitmap Failed.
09-28 09:24:07.740: A/libc(20140): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000004 (code=1)
09-28 09:24:09.750: I/dalvikvm(20367): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 10...
09-28 09:24:09.940: D/dalvikvm(20367): GC_CONCURRENT freed 864K, 21% free 3797K/4771K, paused 2ms+2ms
```

thanks.

[update]

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.showmoredetailslayout);
        actualCallTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.actualcalltime);
        doubleUp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.doubleupcallid);
        needName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.needname);
        needNameLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.neednamelabel);
        getRotaDetails = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttongetrotadetails);
        intent = this.getIntent();
        String actualTimeIn = intent.getStringExtra("actTimeIn");
        String actualTimeOut = intent.getStringExtra("actTimeOut");
        String doubleUpValue = intent.getStringExtra("doubleUpValue");
        String needNameWithCommas = intent.getStringExtra("needNameWithCommas");
        callID = intent.getStringExtra("callID");
        String[] needs = needNameWithCommas.split(",");



        actualCallTime.setText("This call was completed at " + actualTimeIn + " -" + actualTimeOut);
        if( ! doubleUpValue.equalsIgnoreCase("") || doubleUpValue.equalsIgnoreCase("]")){
        doubleUp.setText("This call was not a double up ");
        }else{

            doubleUp.setText("This call was  a double up " + doubleUpValue);
        }

        needNameLabel.setText("Purpose of Call: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < needs.length; i++){
        needName.append( needs[i] + "\n");
        }

        getRotaDetails.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(ShowMoreDetails.this, GetRotaDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra("callIDExtra", callID);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the side of your PNG file?!

Comment: Can you show more of the stack-trace? For some reason something is trying to allocate almost 30MB of memory.

Comment: there is something wrong with your image as it appears to be 28072816 bytes long

Comment: yes an alloc of 28Mb is something very weird.There's something wrong in your code.

Comment: well all i've done is pasted the png from desktop into drawable and set it inside a linearlayout.

Comment: Could you show us ShowMoreDetails oncreate() method?

Comment: @VinceFR i've updated the post to include the oncreate

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the OOM is coming from the setContentView method.the problem comes from your showmoredetailslayout layout file.
Could you remove your last update and replace it by your showmoredetailslayout file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Benito said, PNG needs twice the memory of jpg. Therefore Your options are:

1. Reduce the size of the image.
2. Use JPG, and use an alpha for it. Unfortunately, you can not set alpha in xml, so you should do it programatically (see below).

I would suggest to decrease image size even if you choose option 2, as even if it works on your phone, other models may have less memory. From the log it seems your image is about 2K*3K, which is larger that probably all screens out there.

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.background);
Drawable background = view.getBackground();
background.setAlpha(80);
```

Comment: thanks, i scaled the image down in size, changed it to png, added alpha, saved back as jpg. works great now.

Answer (score 2):

The default `PixelFormat` of your activity's window is `RGB_565`.

When you were using a `JPEG` image, it was being read in `RGB_565` *(16-bit)*.

When you used a `PNG` image with transparency *(alpha values)*, it was read in `RGBA_8888` *(32-bit)*.

Therefore the same image size *(as in dimensions)* needed more memory.

Comment: I'm not reading this image in using a BitmapFactory etc. It's just in my drawable folder and is set in an xml layout file inside a linearLayout tag, eg android:background="@drawable/carefreebgopaque"

Comment: In your original question you ask: *Im getting the following error. why?* You should add: *And how can I solve this?*

Comment: You can't allocate more memory. You have to figure out a way to use less. You could use a smaller image. You could save your image in jpeg format after changing the opacity, because transparency is meaningless if you don't have content below it.

Comment: Hi, i've been working on something else and had to come back to this. I've set the opacity to 20% as a png and now i have exported it in gimp as a jpg. It still running out of memory on my htc one x. tried it on a samsung mini and it works fine. any ideas why it's still out of memory with jpg? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try the bellow links, here you will have some related answers.

[Android VM Out of Memory Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358637/android-vm-out-of-memory-error)

OR

[Android png images big in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410027/android-png-images-big-in-memory)

This may help you.