# android bitmap size exceed VM budget error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using following code to get bitmap from url. This function is used multiple times in my code and on third or fourth call crashes showing following error. Url exists and I am sure that there is no difference between previous calls. Thank you

```
 public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
                try {
                    Log.e("src",src);
                    URL url = new URL(src);
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                    connection.connect();
                    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input); //crashes at this line
                    Log.e("Bitmap","returned");
                    return myBitmap;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("Exception",e.getMessage());
                    return null;
                }
            }

06-15 14:15:34.365: E/AndroidRuntime(863): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-15 14:15:34.365: E/AndroidRuntime(863): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
06-15 14:15:34.365: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
06-15 14:15:34.365: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:459)
06-15 14:15:34.365: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:515)
06-15 14:15:34.365: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at com.nimbosolutions.projecte1.TabBar_iOSActivity.getBitmapFromURL(TabBar_iOSActivity.java:232)
06-15 14:15:34.365: E/AndroidRuntime(863):  at com.nimbosolutions.projecte1.TabBar_iOSActivity.addTab(TabBar_iOSActivity.java:209)
```

Comment: have you [Googled](https://www.google.co.in/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=15&ix=h9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=android+bitmap+size+exceed+VM+budget+error) before asking question?

Comment: yes I did, that is why I am asking it!

Comment: possible duplicate of [OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget :- Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928002/outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said "third or fourth time" - is it the same bitmap every time? If yes, why not cache and reuse?

If no, do you really need all 3-4 bitmaps in memory at the same time? If yes, you're screvved. If not, may I recommend that you call `recycle()` on your bitmaps before you discard them (i. e. before you null the reference)? This is known to free up memory faster than vanilla GC would.

Comment: not the same bitmap. I do not need to 3-4 bitmaps in memory, just one. Do you mean recycle() and then input = null?

Comment: No, the stream is OK (although closing explicitly is not a bad idea). The Bitmap object is the one that needs recycling. It's up to the caller, the one that receives `myBitmap`.