# OutOfMemoryError on android when loading JPG from resources (Samsung Galaxy SIII and emulator)

Tags: android, exception, resources, out-of-memory

I have got an "Out of Memory" exception when I try to load JPG from resources.

The JPG size is 540x960 (80Kb), and there is two such JPGs allready loaded.

This problem occurs on the Samsung Galaxy SIII, on other devices all works fine. Also, the problem occurs on the emulator WXGA/ARM 720x1280 (Android 4.0.3)

What I am doing wrong? How I can find reasons of the problem and fix them? May be there is the problem with bad JPG? Jr there is a bug in SDK/Runtime?

Emulator info:

```
CPU/ABI: ARM (armeabi-v7a)
Target:  Android 4.0.3 (API level 15)
Skin:    WXGA720
SD Card: 1Gb
--------------
hw.mainKeys:    no
hw.lcd.density: 320
hw.keyboard.lid:no
hw.cpu.model:   cortex-a8
vm.heapSize:    48
hw.ramSize:     1024
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget :- Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928002/outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android)

Comment: Take a look at the "Related" section, on the right side of the page.

Comment: Just a note: the size of JPG file is irrelevant.  If you want to determine how much memory the image really takes, save it as uncompressed TIFF image and look at its file size.  This will give you a better indication.  In reality, android needs slightly more than the TIFF file size - to store some additional metadata as well as general java object overhead.

Comment: Thanks, that is complete. Reducing image size removes the problem