# Android ANRs Error

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android area. I have written a Primitive app.

I have a ListView with images and text.

Now I have an error message.

```
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:460)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:501)
at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:280)
at com.PACKAGE.MainActivity$MyListAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:132)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1432)
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1745)
at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:670)
at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:727)
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1598)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1262)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:912)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:343)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:343)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1140)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3714)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:853)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What exactly says this error message? In Which line is the error?

How can I best read and understand a message?

Comment: It means you are working with an image and your image operation exceeds alowed memory size

Comment: Please avoid using "urgent" in your questions.

Comment: take a look at here for possible solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928002/outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android

Comment: maybe android:largeHeap="true" inside the <application>-tag in your AndroidManifest.xml could fix it, otherwise you will have to resize your image or use another workaround.
how many images do you use/ what is their resolution?

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

I have 5 images (png 200x200, 8-15kb) and 1 picture 2200x2048 1.61 MB

Comment: You need to implement lazy loading for your images, so that they are loaded in the background. If you are new you might want to use libraries already available to implement the same. Have a look at Picasso here : https://github.com/square/picasso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First look at the exception
*java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget*
and most probably this is the line in your code 
*at com.PACKAGE.MainActivity$MyListAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:132)* (notice your package)

You tried to load an image larger than your heap supported. The size in MB of the compressed file is of little importance, as any image will be expanded in memory as a bitmap. Thus only the pixel format and pixel count matters. In your case 2200x2048 might me to much.

As possible solutions for the memory problem

- **Use a lower resolution image, or manually load the image using BitmapFactory where you have the option to downsample**
- **Use *android:largeHeap="true"* in manifest might help.** Not good practice, if can be avoided.

The ANR comes because you do a lot of work (loading large image) on the UI thread. Lower resolution image might help also to this problem, but you should consider loading the images in a worker thread
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html, **Worker threads**

Comment: Thank you.

Now it seems to work.

I have the image reduced to 512x512