# Black Screen when stretching Bitmap to fit with screen height

Tags: android, performance, bitmap

I try to load the bitmap to a custom SurfaceView in my first image editor application. It will try to scale the image (up or down) to fit with the screen height (yeah, I know it is stupid function, but I am learning android as well). This is the code in the activity

```
private RelativeLayout topLayout; 
private CustomeSurfaceView customeSurfaceView; 

public void onCreate(Bundle onSaveBundle) {
    // initialize all the views
    ......

    // Scale image to screen
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);

    screenWidth = size.x;
    screenHeight = size.y;

    if (path != null && bmp == null) {
        bmp = AppUtils.loadBitmapFromPath(this, path);
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "Before scaled: " + bmp.getWidth() + " " + bmp.getHeight());

    int scaleHeight = screenHeight;
    int scaleWidth = (int) (((float) screenHeight / bmp.getHeight() * 1.0) * bmp.getWidth());

    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, scaleWidth, scaleHeight, false);

    if (scaledBitmap != bmp) {
        bmp.recycle();
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "After scaled: " + scaledBitmap.getWidth() + " " + scaledBitmap.getHeight());

    // Create the work space and load the bitmap
    customSurfaceView = new CustomeSurfaceView(this, scaledBitmap);
    topLayout.addView(customSurfaceView);

}
```

And this is the code of the SurfaceView

```
public class CustomeSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private Bitmap mainImage; 
    int maxX;
    int maxY;

    private int scrollByX;
    private int scrollByY;
    private int maxLeft;
    private int maxRight;
    private int maxTop;
    private int maxBottom;
    private float downX, downY;
    private int totalX, totalY;
    private float currentXPos;
    private float currentYPos;
    private int screenHeight;
    private int screenWidth;

    public CustomeSurfaceView(Context context, Bitmap bitmap) {
        super(context);

        Display display = ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

        screenWidth = size.x;
        screenHeight = size.y;

        // set maximum scroll amount (based on center of image)
        maxX = (mainImage.getWidth() / 2) - (screenWidth / 2);
        maxY = (mainImage.getHeight() / 2) - (screenHeight / 2);

        // set scroll limits
        maxLeft = (maxX * -1);
        maxRight = maxX;
        maxTop = (maxY * -1);
        maxBottom = maxY;

        this.mainImage = bitmap;
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        .....
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param canvas
     */
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawBitmap(mainImage, maxLeft, 0, null);
    }
}
```

If I try to scale up, say from 1280 * 800 to 2048 * 1280, then SurfaceView happily load my scaled bitmap

[image]

However, if I try to scale down from 3264 * 1840 to 2270 * 1280, I end up with a black screen

[image]

My questions are :

1. What did I do wrong here?
2. If this is not a good way to load the image (for example, can lead to out of memory), what can I do to optimize it? The whole image needs to be loaded so user can scroll, edit on that image

Answer (score 1):

When ever working with `bitmap` or any type of images on Android the one of the biggest risk is the `OutOfMemoryError` which might not come when you are testing and later on appear. Due to lack of `Memory` avaialable in Android device.

The problem have been discused many times on SO and on Android Page
Reference

1. [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928002/outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android)
2. [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object?lq=1)
3. [Android](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

My personal favourite way to tackle image problem is by using [ImageLoader](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/). Try going through `ImageLoader`, its the best.

PS: My app loads around 50-100 pics to `ListView`. Never it crashes.

Comment: Please see my edited question. For the `ListView` loading, I used `Android Image Universal Loader` which is pretty awesome already. I just need to load the full image to the screen in a efficient way since user has to do everything with the whole image