# Showing photos runs out of memory

Tags: java, android, image

I'm using a dialog box to display images in my android project. The first one opens fine, but when I close it and do the process again to show a different one the app falls over with a memory error (it's running on a samsung galaxy s3 - so shouldnt be an issue).

**Error:**

```
10-24 11:25:45.575: E/dalvikvm-heap(29194): Out of memory on a 31961104-byte allocation.
10-24 11:25:45.580: E/AndroidRuntime(29194): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-24 11:25:45.580: E/AndroidRuntime(29194): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
10-24 11:25:45.580: E/AndroidRuntime(29194):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
10-24 11:25:45.580: E/AndroidRuntime(29194):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
10-24 11:25:45.580: E/AndroidRuntime(29194):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:389)
10-24 11:25:45.580: E/AndroidRuntime(29194):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:418)
10-24 11:25:45.580: E/AndroidRuntime(29194):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromPath(Drawable.java:882)
10-24 11:25:45.580: E/AndroidRuntime(29194):    at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:569)
10-24 11:25:45.580: E/AndroidRuntime(29194):    at android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(ImageView.java:340)
10-24 11:25:45.580: E/AndroidRuntime(29194):    at com.directenquiries.assessment.tool.AddAsset.loadPhoto(AddAsset.java:771)
10-24 11:25:45.580: E/AndroidRuntime(29194):    at com.directenquiries.assessment.tool.AddAsset$11.onClick(AddAsset.java:748)
10-24 11:25:45.580: E/AndroidRuntime(29194):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:936)
10-24 11:25:45.580: E/AndroidRuntime(29194):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
10-24 11:25:45.580: E/AndroidRuntime(29194):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1359)
10-24 11:25:45.580: E/AndroidRuntime(29194):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2988)
10-24 11:25:45.580: E/AndroidRuntime(29194):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3783)
10-24 11:25:45.580: E/AndroidRuntime(29194):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-24 11:25:45.580: E/AndroidRuntime(29194):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-24 11:25:45.580: E/AndroidRuntime(29194):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-24 11:25:45.580: E/AndroidRuntime(29194):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
10-24 11:25:45.580: E/AndroidRuntime(29194):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-24 11:25:45.580: E/AndroidRuntime(29194):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-24 11:25:45.580: E/AndroidRuntime(29194):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
10-24 11:25:45.580: E/AndroidRuntime(29194):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
10-24 11:25:45.580: E/AndroidRuntime(29194):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Loading code:**

```
public void loadPhotoList(){

    Cursor f = db.rawQuery("select * from stationphotos where StationObjectID =  '"+ checkStationObjectID + "'", null);  
    final ArrayList<String> mHelperNames= new ArrayList<String>();

            if(f.getCount() != 0) {
              f.moveToFirst();

                f.moveToFirst();
                while(!f.isAfterLast()) {
                    mHelperNames.add(f.getString(f.getColumnIndex("FilePath")));
                    f.moveToNext();
                }
            }
     f.close();
     final String [] nameStrings = new String [mHelperNames.size()];

     for(int i=0; i<mHelperNames.size(); i++)
        nameStrings[i] = mHelperNames.get(i).toString();


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setTitle("Select Picture");
    builder.setItems(nameStrings, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

          loadPhoto(mHelperNames.get(item).toString());

       }

    });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

    alert.show();

 }


public void loadPhoto(String imagepath){

    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_image);
    dialog.setTitle("Image");
    dialog.setCancelable(true);

    ImageView img = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ico_partial);
    Uri imgUri = Uri.parse(imagepath);
    img.setImageURI(imgUri);


    dialog.show();
}
```

**Edit:** What i'm using to make it now work:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String imagePath, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);
}
    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}



img.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(imagepath, 500, 500));
```

Comment: What does memory profiler shows? What's heap size, heap free memory?

Comment: Heap shot up to 44mb when I loaded the photo. Is there another way to do it? 1 45.258 MB 44.830 MB 438.242 KB 99.05% 57,128

Comment: How you know the height and width is 500?

Comment: I don't really remember (4 years ago!?) but it looks like it should always be 500 by 500 for whatever purpose i needed it - last line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have experienced this and I don't know if my answer is best practice or not however...

This is probably your problem:

```
Uri imgUri = Uri.parse(imagepath);
    img.setImageURI(imgUri);
```

> Heap shot up to 44mb when I loaded the photo.

If you load a large image then you are probably going to run out of memory. Also you will run out of memory if you fail to use decent memory management when loading a series of images.

I used the [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) to decode the file and used the [BitmapFactory.Options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) to create a new sclaed Bitmap that I then displayed on screen.

The idea is that the BitmapFactory.Options gives you more control over the potential memory that your image could use up. For example there is no need to show a 1920x1080 image at full size on a screen that does not even support those resolutions.

There are some related stackoverflow questions that might help you and in particular: [Handling large Bitmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220949/handling-large-bitmaps), which focuses on the BitmapFactory.Options option `inJustDecodeBounds`.

Finally, I have found this great lightweight library called [Aquery](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/). It has a whole raft of methods for handling large files, and so far it does it well. Well worth a look. It uses a similar paradigm to Jquery in respect of web development (hence the name) and introduces a shorter syntax for manipulating Views. The following section of their documentation deals with image loading both locally and from a remote source, including fall back images:

http://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading

Comment: Thanks for this, i just looked in to the bitmap factory and now i'm compressing as i go