# Bitmap is always null, however file path is correct

Tags: android, android-bitmap

This is my code to load `Bitmap` into `ImageView` from `filepath` retrieved from another activity.
I can get file, but `Bitmap` is always `null`.

I have tried with 250kb image code works fine but it does not work with 1.5MB images.How to resolve this issue?

Logcat message:

```
skia:           --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
Choreographer:  Skipped 855 frames! `The application may be doing too much work on its main thread`.
```

code

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String imagepath = extras.getString("FILEPATH1");
    File imgFile = new  File(imagepath);
        if(imgFile.exists()){                   
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());                    
            imgCaptured.setImageBitmap(bitmap);                         
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: Post full code. Are you using `AsyncTask`?

Comment: You have a answer in your own question, make a separate thread for Bitmap working.

Comment: @SmartphoneDeveloper: in separate thread it was also giving null. I tried it also earlier!

Comment: Are you sure imgFile is valid image file?

Comment: What is your absolute path?

Comment: @mata:yes imgFile is .jpg file

Comment: @vokilam: this is my path: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/CameraSample/IMG_20140813_164958_-244780148.jpg

Comment: It's possible that the image couldn't be loaded or decoded...try with another simpler image to see if you get different results.

Comment: @Kevan, You have defined the read and write permission in AndroidManifest.xml? Otherwise file may be large size please try with another small size file.

Answer (score 2):

As Javadocs say:

```
Returns: the resulting decoded bitmap, or null if it could not be decoded.
```

So, if you successfully can load a small bitmap from the same file but larger file fails, it is a strong indicator to the size being a problem. Most likely decoding the 1.5M JPEG file would result in a bitmap that is over 10M in size. Your phone can not load an image that big.

BTW, you can estimate the uncompressed size of the image by multiplying the width and height and multiplying that by 4 (one byte per channel: red, green, blue, alpha).

For example, a 2.6M JPEG that has 4128x2322 pixels takes about 38340000bytes (38M) when uncompressed.

This may help: [Handling large Bitmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220949/handling-large-bitmaps)

Comment: On Android Developers website is nice article about loading large images efficiently http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html