# How to solve application auto stop in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-gridview, android-image

I have designed a gridview in my android layout, where I am showing images as grid items by picking them from my device. When I am trying to run that app my application running correctly for the first time. But, when I am trying to add pictures to the gridview again by clicking add pictures button, then its force closing my application.

```
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): Process: com.example.imagepicfromgallery, PID: 21288
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:635)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:611)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:391)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:417)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at com.example.imagepicfromgallery.CustomList.getView(CustomList.java:33)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2300)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1345)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:345)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:287)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.widget.GridView.fillFromTop(GridView.java:421)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.widget.GridView.layoutChildren(GridView.java:1233)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2149)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2323)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2029)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1192)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6231)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
01-23 16:40:56.762: E/AndroidRuntime(21288): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

//private LinearLayout lnrImages;
GridView lnrImages;
private Button btnAddPhots;
private Button btnSaveImages;
private ArrayList<String> imagesPathList;
private Bitmap yourbitmap;
private Bitmap resized;
private final int PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE =1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lnrImages = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grdImages);
    btnAddPhots = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddPhots);
    btnSaveImages = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSaveImages);
    btnAddPhots.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSaveImages.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnAddPhots:
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CustomPhotoGalleryActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE);
            break;
        case R.id.btnSaveImages:
            if(imagesPathList !=null){
                if(imagesPathList.size()>1) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, imagesPathList.size() + " no of images are selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, imagesPathList.size() + " no of image are selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this," no images are selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
    }
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE){
            imagesPathList = new ArrayList<String>();
            String[] imagesPath = data.getStringExtra("data").split("\\|");
            CustomList adapter = new
                    CustomList(MainActivity.this,imagesPath);
            lnrImages.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

}

}
```

CustomList.java

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

private final Activity context;
private final String[] web;

public CustomList(Activity context,
String[] web) {
super(context, R.layout.list_single, web);
this.context = context;
this.web = web;


}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);


imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(web[position]));
return rowView;
}
}
```

CustomPhotoGalleryActivity.java

```
public class CustomPhotoGalleryActivity extends Activity {

private GridView grdImages;
private Button btnSelect;

private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
private String[] arrPath;
private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
private int ids[];
private int count;


/**
 * Overrides methods
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_gallery);
    grdImages= (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grdImages);
    btnSelect= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelect);

    final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,    MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
    final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor imagecursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,  columns, null, null, orderBy);
    int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
    this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
    this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
    ids = new int[count];
    this.thumbnailsselection = new boolean[this.count];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
        imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
        ids[i] = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
        int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        arrPath[i] = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
    }

    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
    grdImages.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    imagecursor.close();


    btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            final int len = thumbnailsselection.length;
            int cnt = 0;
            String selectImages = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (thumbnailsselection[i]) {
                    cnt++;
                    selectImages = selectImages + arrPath[i] + "|";
                }
            }
            if (cnt == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select at least one image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {

                Log.d("SelectedImages", selectImages);
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.putExtra("data", selectImages);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
    super.onBackPressed();

}

/**
 * Class method
 */

/**
 * This method used to set bitmap.
 * @param iv represented ImageView 
 * @param id represented id
 */

private void setBitmap(final ImageView iv, final int id) {

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            iv.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }.execute();
}


/**
 * List adapter
 * @author tasol
 */

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ImageAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_gallery_item, null);
            holder.imgThumb = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgThumb);
            holder.chkImage = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkImage);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.chkImage.setId(position);
        holder.imgThumb.setId(position);
        holder.chkImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                int id = cb.getId();
                if (thumbnailsselection[id]) {
                    cb.setChecked(false);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                } else {
                    cb.setChecked(true);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                }
            }
        });
        holder.imgThumb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                int id = holder.chkImage.getId();
                if (thumbnailsselection[id]) {
                    holder.chkImage.setChecked(false);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                } else {
                    holder.chkImage.setChecked(true);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                }
            }
        });
        try {
            setBitmap(holder.imgThumb, ids[position]);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
        }
        holder.chkImage.setChecked(thumbnailsselection[position]);
        holder.id = position;
        return convertView;
    }
}


/**
 * Inner class
 * @author tasol
 */
class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imgThumb;
    CheckBox chkImage;
    int id;
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.imagepicfromgallery.MainActivity" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grdImages"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddPhots"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Phots"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSaveImages"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

custom_gallery_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgThumb"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chkImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|right"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

custom_gallery.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grdImages"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSelect"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Select"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

list_single.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have enabled the permission to read and write to external storage in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thanks Sir, but now i am getting some new error in my logcat.

01-23 14:31:37.077: E/(15977): appName=com.example.imagepicfromgallery, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger
01-23 14:31:37.077: E/(15977): 0
01-23 14:31:37.077: E/(15977): appName=com.example.imagepicfromgallery, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger
01-23 14:31:37.077: E/(15977): 0

Comment: 01-23 15:28:04.294: E/(17900): appName=com.example.imagepicfromgallery, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger
01-23 15:28:04.294: E/(17900): 0
01-23 15:28:04.294: E/(17900): appName=com.example.imagepicfromgallery, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger
01-23 15:28:04.294: E/(17900): 0

Comment: Sir my application running correctly for the first time. But, when i am trying to add pictures to the gridView again by clicking add pictures button, then its force closing my application.

Comment: @SritamJagadev please use https://justpaste.it/ to include full output from logcat as the previous does not describe the full error.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the edited question:

You're running out of memory when handling the images. If you're using an android emulator, make sure it's configured to use commonly big memory 1GB +.

[Android discusses handling large bitmaps here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

and

[Here's a topic stackoverflow on how to handle large bitmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220949/handling-large-bitmaps)

You can also try and add 
        `android:largeHeap="true"` to the AndroidManifest under `<application`

Comment: Sir i am using My mobile (iball slide 6095-q700) to debug my program. Also my device having more than 8gb empty space but still facing same problem.