# Storing images in Content Provider

Tags: android, image, sd-card, android-contentprovider

I have been surfing for good ways store images in android,  and landed in this question [Where to save pictures on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847664/where-to-save-pictures-on-android)

Few doubts
1. There was no mention of use of content provider for images, is it a good practice or not.
2. If stored in a raw folder, would that affect the execution time of query rather as compared to storing in res/drwable folder

thnx for help i need it in urgent :)

Comment: Where would content providers save the images for themselfs?